# Getting minimize and maximize events on internet explorer

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, activex

I have a legacy ActiveX component which runs embedded in IE. Now I want to perform some action when IE window minimized and maximized by the user. Can anybody provide any clue on how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an expert in this topic. But after some research what I could find was,

> To sink Internet Explorer events from the activex control, you have to
>   set up the event sink, which means you must obtain the [`IWebBrowser2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
>   interface implemented by Internet Explorer when it loads.

See this document for more info on [Handling internet explorer events](http://vbyte.com/iReader/Reader.asp?ISBN=0735607818&URI=/HTML/ch07g.htm)

In `IWebBrowser2` I could find only find `IWebBrowser2::FullScreen` and `IWebBrowser2::TheaterMode` to be somewhat similar to your requirement.
However, there is another property `IWebBrowser2::HWND` that you can use to get the window handle of internet explorer.

On a wild thought, (I don't know whether its applicable for activeX controls) consider [Using hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx).

Also found: [IE add-on development: capturing keyboard input outside tabs](http://www.ookii.org/post/ie_addon_development_capturing_keyboard_input_outside_tabs.aspx)